# Is it possible to create bootable USB stick on 512 Mb flash drive?

Tags: 10.10, boot, usb-drive

I have only 512 Mb flash drive. Is it possible to create bootable Maverick 10.10 on it? Maybe, with some packages dropped? What tool can I try for it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try using **Ubuntu Customization Kit** available here http://uck.sourceforge.net
it let you create a custom distribution based on Ubuntu with packages you need. You should also be able to customize language pack, default language, keyboard layout ecc... I hope it helps.

Comment: Well, I must make up .iso <512 Mb and write it using usb-creator? It will work? I don't believe that's so simple :)

Comment: well, you just have to remove useless software, for example games, languages you don't use ecc.... then your iso fill fit 512Mb.

Answer (score 2):

There are many light weight distributions such as [Lubuntu](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lubuntu/ReleaseNotes/MaverickMeerkat), [Xubuntu](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Xubuntu/MaverickMeerkat/Final), [EasyPeasy](http://edge.geteasypeasy.com/about/) (soon with 10.10 based version 1.7.), [Puppy](http://puppylinux.org/main/Overview%20and%20Getting%20Started.htm) (still based on Lucid) - to name just a few - that have already done the job. If you need additional packages or another desktop you can alway install this later until your flash drive is full.

Comment: I want Ubuntu with Gnome :) But thanks for answer!

Comment: I see. Multiple dependencies would install lots of fancy stuff. It's this that could make gnome-desktop too large to fit on to your flash. That depends entirely on what you need in addition.